# Adding a uniqueidentifier column and adding the default to generate new guid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserProfiles
ADD ChatId UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(ChatId),
CONSTRAINT "ChatId_default" SET DEFAULT newid()
```

I want to be able to make this column unique, and I want it to be able to generate a new guid every time a row is added to the table.  This column is not an IDENTITY column because I already have one.  This is something separate. How would I go about adding this column to a table with users already in it.

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server expert, but I believe that you should: (1) create it nullable (2) run an update like `set = NewGuid() where is null` (3) `alter` it to `not null default NewGuid()`

Comment: Why would you need an arbitrary unique column value if you already have a unique identity column?  Are you migrating to a new key system in that table?

Comment: @AndreCalil is correct in the methodology, although I think the correct function name for T-SQL is `NEWID()`

Comment: @pseudocoder, one purpose that comes to mind is to use as an external reference in a system that pulls from various sources.  Integers that are unique within the source scope are likely collide when moving to the aggregate system.

Comment: @pseudocoder replication also requires that you set up unique guid columns

Answer (score 42, accepted):

see this sample:

```
create table test (mycol UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL default newid(), name varchar(100))
insert into test (name) values ('Roger Medeiros')
select * from test
```

for add a not null field on a populated table you need this.

```
alter table test add mycol2 UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL default newid() with values

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_test ON dbo.test
(
mycol
) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: As the OP explained, the table already exists.  And it needs a unique constraint.  And data has already been added

Comment: I do not see the need for the restriction is that the field is of type unique identifier

Comment: That depends on if the data is ever passed in directly without using the `default`.  Better safe than sorry...

Comment: then just create the unique index for the column, see again the example.

Answer (score 18):

Don't use `newid()` as default, instead use [newsequentialid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx). `newid()` creates a lot of fragmentation and that's bad for indexes.

As far as adding the new column to a table with existing data, simply do this:

```
    ALTER TABLE your_table
    ADD your_column UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT newsequentialid() NOT null
```

Comment: If privacy is a concern, do not use newsequentialid(). It is possible to guess the value of the next generated GUID and, therefore, access data associated with that GUID

Comment: This is the tradeoff. Fragmentation or speed? Take your pick.

Comment: Fragmentation would only be an issue if the column is indexed.